# How to assign a rank number to an array when ties exist

Tags: php

I am struggling to know where to start when trying to assign ranks to the numeric values in an array when there are ties. So, for example, I need to turn an array like the following:

```
myarray = (4,76,34,13,34)
```

into another array like:

```
myarray2 = (1,5,3.5,2,3.5)
```

Basically, when the same number occurs more than once in the array, the assigned rank to those numbers is the average of the ranks. So, instead of the two 34s being ranked 3 and 4 they both get assigned 3.5. Similarly, if there were 3 copies of 34 then the 3 assigned ranks would be divided by 3. Any help would be much appreciated!

Many thanks,

Adam

Comment: And I don't find any particular scheme between the two forms of array.

Comment: That's a very unusual method of handling ties.

Comment: To explain more: If I were to rank the numbers normally within the array:

myarray = (4,76,34,13,34)

and put those ranks in another array then it would look like:

myarray2 = (1,5,3,2,4) 

with PHP randomly deciding which of the identical values (in this case the number 34) gets the rank 3 and which gets the rank 4. However, for the problem I am trying to solve, instead of assigning the ranks 3 and 4 to these duplicate values, the ranks (3 and 4) should be averaged. Therefore, the "34" values that appear twice  both get assigned the value of 3.5 in the array of ranks (myarray2).

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve is a statistical problem, hence why this method of ranking might seem strange.

Comment: The closest I had come to a solution was to rank the array so that: myarray = (4,13,34,34,76) and then turn this into a multi-dimensional array by adding the above array's key into the array. Then loop throught myarray (already ranked) for each value and see if all values thereafter are identical to the current one. If they are, count how many, grab the ranks (now in multi-dimensional array), divide by the count and insert into the array. But it seems very convulted and have not got it to work yet.

Comment: @Frank - It's not unusual in some statistical tests. For example for the Spearman's Rank Correlation Coefficient, if ties exist in your rankings, `one has to assign the same rank to each of the equal values. It is an average of their positions in the ascending order of the values.`

Comment: @Peter - You guessed it! It is the Spearman Rank I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had fun with this one!

```
function rank($input) 
{
  $output = array();
  $ranking = $input; sort($ranking); $ranking = array_flip($ranking);
  $last_val = -1;
  foreach($ranking as $key => $val){
    $repetitions = ($val-$last_val-1);
    $last_val = $val;
    if($repetitions) {    
      $ranking[$key] = (($val*($repetitions+1))-($repetitions+1)*(($repetitions)/2))/($repetitions+1)+1 ;
    } else {
      $ranking[$key] = $val+1;
    }
  }
  foreach($input as $key => $val){
    $output[$key] = $ranking[$val];
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$a = array(4,76,34,13,34);    
$c = rank($a);
print_r($c);
```

will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 3.5
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 3.5
)
```

wich is the same as:

```
Array(1, 5, 3.5, 2, 3.5)
```

as expected!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it.

```
<?php
$myarray       = array(4,76,34,13,34);

$sorted_array  = $myarray;
$grouped_array = array();
sort($sorted_array);
foreach ($sorted_array as $rank => $entry) {
    // Initialize the entry if it doesn't already exist
    if (empty($grouped_array[$entry])) {
        $grouped_array[$entry]['count'] = 1.0;
        $grouped_array[$entry]['total'] = $rank + 1; // Account for 0-based array
    } else {
        $grouped_array[$entry]['count'] += 1.0;
        $grouped_array[$entry]['total'] += $rank + 1; // Account for 0-based array
    }
}
$myarray2 = array();
foreach ($myarray as $entry) {
    // Get the average
    $myarray2[] = $grouped_array[$entry]['total'] / $grouped_array[$entry]['count'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you also need to handle the cases where there are three or four or *n* values tied at the same rank.

I'm no PHP guru, but here's an approach (pseudo code) to defining a rank function:

```
define a = original array
define s = a.Sorted
define rank(n) = (s.FirstIndexOf(n) + s.LastIndexOf(n)) / 2
```

You may need to work a few examples on paper to convince yourself that this works even for triples and higher; it's reliant on `s` being sorted so that duplicates are adjacent.

Comment: How you do get the values of s back into the order of the input array?

Comment: You don't put `s` back into order, you don't need to (and you couldn't, anyway). `a` is your original array, in original order. `s` is a *copy*.

Comment: does this assume the array to be 0 or 1-index based?

Comment: It doesn't make any assumption on the array having any particular base.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution (and others too) seem to be way more complicated than they need to be:

```
function Rank($data) {
    $count = 0;
    $unique = $data; sort($unique);
    $unique = array_count_values($unique);

    foreach ($unique as $key => $frequency) {
        foreach (range(1, $frequency) as $i) {
            $unique[$key] += $count++;
        }

        $unique[$key] /= $frequency;
    }

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = $unique[$value];
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Example ([demo](http://codepad.org/bWF9F1vv)):

```
print_r(Rank(array(4, 76, 34, 13, 34))); // 1; 5; 3.5; 2; 3.5
print_r(Rank(array(4, 76, 34, 13, 34, 34))); // 1; 6; 4; 2; 4; 4
```