# Rank Average with PHP

Tags: php, math, formula, ranking

In Excel there's a function Rank Average ([see documentation](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Rank-Avg-Function.html)).

I wish to do the same in PHP. Looking online, I find a lot of ranking solutions, but not a lot of those take duplicates into account and when they do, the result I get is not the same as Excel is giving me at all. It's very important it does though.

Ideally, what I'd need is a function that requires a score and array to compare it with, and give me the rank for it.

Example with some actual date from Excel:

```
$array = array(5.80,6.00,6.00,5.60,3.20,3.00,3.60,5.70,3.60,1.90,5.00,5.80,3.00,3.80,5.00,3.00,6.00,5.70,5.00,4.90,4.20,3.60,5.00,4.90,4.90,3.00
3.30,4.80,4.60,4.10,4.70,6.00,3.30,4.30,4.30,3.00,3.10,6.00,1.90,3.80,5.00,2.00,2.80,3.00,4.20,3.00,5.50,6.00,5.00,5.00);

$score1 = 5.80;
$score2 = 6.00;

$rank1 = rankAvg($score1, $array); //should return 7.5
$rank2 = rankAvg($score2, $array); //should return 3.5
```

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: I have, but didn't get the correct result either.

Comment: You should post the code that you have tried. Then we could try to fix it. Don't expect people here to give you ready solution.

Comment: sort array in request order and take index of value. if not found, return NULL

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't solve the possible duplicates

Comment: Did you try just running the array in `array_unique` to get rid of those ?

Comment: Find all indexes and count avr

Comment: According to the description of that Excel function - you need to take in account those duplications as they effect on the rank.

Comment: Yes, the duplicates affect the rank. Deleting from the array is not an option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463732/how-to-assign-a-rank-number-to-an-array-when-ties-exist

Comment: @adeneo Okey, the stack overflow you linked fixed it for me, but not the accepted answer there. The last one was the gold one, though after some alterations :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function rank_avg($value, $array, $order = 0) {
// sort  
  if ($order) sort ($array); else rsort($array);
// add item for counting from 1 but 0
  array_unshift($array, $value+1); 
// select all indexes vith the value
  $keys = array_keys($array, $value);
  if (count($keys) == 0) return NULL;
// calculate the rank
  return array_sum($keys) / count($keys);
}

echo rank_avg(25, array(20,23,25,27,29), 1);
```

Comment: This is perfect and what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This one right here did the trick for me (http://codepad.org/bWF9F1vv), but I had to change some things.

```
public function rankAvg($rangeArr)
{
    $count = 0;
    $unique = $rangeArr; arsort($unique);
    $unique = array_count_values($unique);

    foreach ($unique as $key => $frequency) {
        foreach (range(1, $frequency) as $i) {
            $unique[$key] += $count++;
        }

        $unique[$key] /= $frequency;
    }

    foreach ($rangeArr as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = $rangeArr[$key] . ': '. $unique[$value];
    }

    return $data;
}
```

It returns a full array though, rather then a value for a given score. But it'll do.