# How to remove a row from result_array() with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Background**

I am creating a ranking system which retrieves a bunch of records to compare their grades, put it on rank and delete that record for the next comparison. However, I'm having trouble on how to delete the record I tried `unset()` but it does not seems to work either.

**Question**

This the code that I'm using. Please take note that this is just pseudo-code of what we are doing and is not the actual code just to avoid confusions from the question. Take a look at this code:

```
// Retrive all the student records with grades.
$students = $this->grades->RetrieveRecords();

// Occupy slot.
$iterator=0;
$highest_index =0 ;
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){

    // Search student for rank $i.

    foreach($students as $student)
    {
        // Some comparisons

        // consider we found the highest yet.
        if($highest<$student['grade']){

            // Store which index it is, because it will be deleted
            // on the next cycle if this $student['grade'] is indeed the highest on this cycle.
            $highest_index = $iterator;
        }
        $iterator+=1;
    }   

    // After getting the highest for rank $i. Delete that current record
    // from $students so on next cycle, it will be removed from the comparison.

    $unset($students[$highest_index]); // Does not work, any alternative? - Greg

    // Reset the foreach iterator for next comparison cycle.
    $iterator=0;
```

The `$unset($students[$highest_index]);` is the one we need to do the job but doesn't. We just need to delete a specific record from `result_array()` which is the `$students`. For now we ran out of alternatives and still searching across the internet/documentations. However, I'll just leave this here for some help.

We will also update this if ever we got a solution for the few hours.

Comment: At this point, I'm currently looking into changing methods upon reading [Rank average with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568812/rank-average-with-php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [array_filter](http://php.net/array-filter):

```
$students = array_filter($students, function($student) use($highest)
{
    return $student['grade'] < $highest;
});
```